# java access control to function modules

Tags: java, security

It is a common requirement that a login user is assigned role and with that role can perform certain task or have access to certain module.

Is there any mature access control framework in Java that can be used?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) framework. It's mature.